# Why do type parameters disappear in TypeScript?

Tags: generics, functional-programming, typescript, type-systems

It seems like TypeScript is not capable of expressing a function which takes a generic function as a parameter and returns a generic function. Note the generic type `<A>` becoming `{}` in the following code sample with the function `doubleton`:

```
function compose<A, B, C>(
        g: (b: B) => C,
        f: (a: A) => B):  (a: A) => C {
    return a => g(f(a));
}

function singleton<A>(a: A): A[] { return [a]; }

// declare var doubleton: (a: {}) => {}[];
var doubleton = compose(singleton, singleton);
```

Oh no! We lost our type parameter `A`.

```
var x = 1; // number
var xs = singleton(x); // number[]
var xss = doubleton(x); // {}[]
```

And now we've seen the effects of `doubleton`'s loss of genericity.
Because of it, `number` became `{}`.

Is there some way to specify make `compose` preserve these type parameters, other than defining `doubleton` as follows?

```
function doubleton<A>(a: A) { return [[a]]; }
```

I know it seems trivial in this example, but I've run into more complex return-type cases (such as auto-curried functions) where it is non-trivial to reiterate yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the issue report : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/417

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be in the way type information of the form of *function signatures* interact with generic parameters. e.g. a simpler example (based on yours) that fails :

```
function mirror<A, B>(f: (a: A) => B)
    : (a: A) => B {
    return f;
}

function singleton<A>(a: A): A[] { return [a]; }

// (a:{})=>{}[]
var singletonMirror = mirror(singleton);

var x = 1;
var xs = singleton(x); // number[]
var xsM = singletonMirror(x); // {}[]
```

Will work if you do not ask the type system to infer `A` and `B` from `f`:

```
function mirror<T>(f: T)
    : T {
    return f;
}

function singleton<A>(a: A): A[] { return [a]; }

// okay
var singletonMirror = mirror(singleton);

var x = 1;
var xs = singleton(x); // number[]
var xsM = singletonMirror(x); // number[]
```

I would report it as an issue : https://github.com/microsoft/typescript/issues

A further simplification of the error:

```
function unity<A>(f: (a: A) => A)
    : (a: A) => A {
    return f;
}

function mirror<T>(a: T): T { return a; }

// (a:{})=>{}, should be (a:T)=>T
var unityMirror = unity(mirror);
```

Comment: `mirror` is a good simplification, I'll make use of it when filing an issue.

Interestingly, I get this same loss of genericity issue when trying to model this in Scala as well. It works correctly in Haskell, though.